# Ruby on Rails - Displaying textfield based on selected ID

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created an input form for orders whereby I select an `client` as follows:

```
<div class="field">  
  <%= f.label :client_short, "Client Code Short" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:client_short, Client.order(:shortname), :shortname, :shortname)%>
</div>
```

Another column of the `Client`is the column `fullname`. Now I want to retrieve and display in a non-editable textfield the value of the fullname based on the shortname for validation during the order entry.

I have no idea were to start so can somebody help me with an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javascript` for this kind of task. I will make an example with pure `jQuery` and `javascript`, not using `coffescript`. Open up your `client.js` (former `client.js.coffee`, just rename it), and add an `change` event to your list, displaying the full name on another field:

```
$(function() {
  $('#list_id').change(function() {
    var client_id = $(this).val();
    $.get('/clients/get_fullname', client_id, function() { });
  });
});
```

Now you, have to create a action on your controller name `get_fullname`, that respond to `javascript`. Maybe something like this:

```
def get_fullname
  @full_name = Client.find(params[:client_id]).fullname
  respond_to |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Now you create a `get_fullname.js.erb` file on your `/views` folder that displays the name on the uneditable field:

```
$('#uneditable_field_id').val("<%= @item %>")
```

Just check some minor typos and syntax errors and you are good to go.
Remember that this is just one way of many to do something like this.

Comment: Super, I will test this shortly! Thanks.